# VS2010 Plugins/Extensions for developing for Powershell?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, visual-studio-extensions

I've googled for awhile now and I'm not finding exactly what I'm looking for (if they're even out there).

I'm looking for a project template for writing Cmdlet and PSCmdlet snap ins as well as a plug in for writing ps1 scripts. I'm also open to trying any other dev tools for Powershell that you may recommend.

Where can I find these and other dev tools for Powershell?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at PowerGUI VSX - http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/

http://poshoholic.com/2010/06/20/powergui-visual-studio-is-now-in-beta/

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the MS Powershell Editor that comes installed with the standard SDK. Alternatively, [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org/index.jspa) is a good one too. It also has [VS 2010 Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/01516103-d487-4a7e-bb40-c15ec709afa3)

Also look at [PowerConsole](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3) extension that lets you run PS commands within VS.